# Which method to use to scale/mean center a time-varying covariate in latent growth models (SEM)?

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, time-varying-covariate, centering, growth-model

I have longitudinal data across several time points. At each time point, participants completed an online test up to 3 times (i.e., measurements were completed 1-3 times at each timepoint). The number of times a participant repeated the test was optional, with participants generally completing the test more times at baseline.

I plan to run latent growth models (SEM) on this data to model the average test scores over time to look at the trajectories of test performance. However, I would like to take into account the number of times a participant completed a test at a given timepoint. Therefore I plan to include the number of times a participant completed the test at each timepoint as an unconditional time-varying covariate (TVC).

I'm wondering which method of scaling is most appropriate in this circumstance for my TVC (i.e., number of times the test was taken). Mean-centering using:

A) the mean across all timepoints for each participant (i.e., person-mean centered),

B) the mean across all participants and timepoints (i.e., grand-mean centered), or

C) the mean of first time point (or other referent point) across all participants (i.e., group-mean centered/centering within context)?